# How to create a function that populates TEXTAREA using multiple textbox in PHP/Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

can u help me  to create a function/script using PHP

I want my project like StackOverflow while creating/typing this query it automatically shows the text in the textarea and also showing the field name inside the textarea, below is my script and sample screenshots:

this is my script

Contact Number    
Account Number

```
<script>
function myFunction() {


    var a = document.getElementById("an").value; /* input box */
    document.getElementById("myTextarea").innerHTML = a; /* text area */

}

</script>

<button onclick="myFunction()">SUBMIT</button>
```

**-- current result --**

[image]

**-- my expected result --**

[image]

Comment: You've tagged jquery, but you're title says you want this in php/javascript,?

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen jQuery is a javascript plugin so still a method of javascript... just shorthand/ pre-programmed...

Comment: @NewToJS I don't think you understood me, he want the solution in either javascript or php, then there is no reason to tag jquery

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I don't think you seem to understand that jQuery is javascript... It's just pre-programmed to make things easier for people to use with the added benefit of keeping the source code smaller which some find easier to read/add/edit.

Comment: @NewToJS I'm gonna leave it here, you don't seem to understand the system of tagging and how it should be used.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen The system for tagging would be `javascript` "vanilla" is the current javascript being used but what if the OP is open for jQuery solutions too? That would be a good reason for tagging `jQuery` right? Have a nice day.

Comment: @NewToJS You would normally add jQuery tag if it had something to do with your question or if you wanted to "allow" a solution in that language, since none of these apply here, then there is no point of adding the tag

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen How do you know the OP isn't open for a jQuery solution? You didn't ask.... So normally when one is open for a jQuery solution that person would tag it.... Maybe ask and confirm if the OP is wanting a jQuery solution, if not then request the tag to be removed. Common sense.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147157/discussion-between-carsten-lovbo-andersen-and-newtojs).

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Very lame of you to downvote on everything I have on my profile. Trying to damage my reputation on my account isn't going to change anything.

Comment: @NewToJS I'm sorry but i haven't done any of this. I don't know if it's questions or answer that has been downvoted, but if its answers, my rep would also have changed, and it haven't. But SO runs a script each 24 hours, that will look for stuff like this and revoke it. So it should get back to normal for you. 

I've like to point out that even though you and I didn't agree i would not and have not downvoted you for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only using one of the inputs

```js
function myFunction() {
  /* input box */
  var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  var text = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    text += inputs[i].getAttribute('aria-label') + ": " + inputs[i].value + "\n";
  }
  /* text area */
  document.getElementById("myTextarea").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
Contact Number <input id="cbr" aria-label="Contact Number" type="text"><br/>
Account Number <input id="an" aria-label="Account Number" type="text">
<textarea id="myTextarea" readonly></textarea><br/>
<button onclick="myFunction()" type="button">SUBMIT</button>
```

I've created a fiddle for you to play with https://jsfiddle.net/0rkwjz3d/

Comment: Thanks, Bro!!  it's working... I forgot to mention bro,,, can u add functions to clear all fields after submitting the record?

Comment: @ReynanSantiago just add `inputs[i].value='';` after `text +=...` Don't add it before otherwise you will remove the value because it is added into the text variable.

Comment: Also great answer! I did plan to offer a vanilla solution too but since this works I have decided to write a jQuery solution for those who stumble on this seeking help and looking for a jQuery solution. https://jsfiddle.net/hatqupaa/

Comment: Correction to above comment *"because it is added into the text variable"* => "**before** it is added into the text variable"

Comment: Hi @NewToJS .. not working or is there incorrect coding?

    <script>
    function myFunction() {
    
    
        var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input"); /* input box */
        var text = "";
        for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
         text += inputs[i].getAttribute('aria-label') + ": " + inputs[i].value=''   + inputs[i].value + "\n";
        }
        
        document.getElementById("myTextarea").innerHTML = text; /* text area */
    }
    
    </script>

Comment: @ReynanSantiago No that isn't correct. I looks like you have added it in the wrong place. Please read the comment again. you need to add it "After" not "to"

Comment: Hi @NewToJS, can u rewrite the code for me, please?  , honestly, it's my first time to write a javascript code

Comment: @ReynanSantiago Okay, I have added a comment above the line so you can see where I have added it. Keep in mind, browsers read like us... from the top left, to the right and then down... so when programming things order matters. https://jsfiddle.net/s66xzahL/

Comment: Hi @NewToJS , Thank you ! :)

Comment: Hi @NewToJS, sorry , can u assist me again?

I added ..  radio box and select on my previous form .. can u help me again to populate it on the textarea ?

Comment: Offer Made 
    <input type="radio" name="offermade" value="Upgrade">Upgrade &nbsp
       <input type="radio" name="offermade" value="Addbox">Addbox<br>
Offer Successfu
<select class="textbox"  name="refer">
<option value="" selected="selected">---------- Select ----------</option>
<option value="YES">YES</option>
<option value="NO">NO</option>
<option value="Undecided">Undecided</option>

</select>
<textarea id="myTextarea" readonly></textarea><br/>
<button onclick="myFunction()" type="button">SUBMIT</button>

Comment: @ReynanSantiago you will need to submit another question but I suggest you read and understand the answer given within this post so you can learn from it which will lead you to use the same functionality on other forms/elements just like what you're asking for now.